# "Notice added" Insufficient explanation by moderator

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

Today I came across a question [**What is the Big O of these values? [on hold]**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18860787/what-is-the-big-o-of-these-values) in which I saw a message

[image]

Then I check the revision where I saw a message from Modeator like

> "Notice added" Insufficient explanation by moderator

I couldn't understand what it means?  However this is put on hold as off-topic later.  *A Moderator reviewed with a notice and then it is closed by other* Why it happened so?

Comment: A moderator added the notice but **the community** closed the question, not another moderator.

Comment: lets delete the question and close the chapter .. this question shows no efforts not useful for future visitor :)

Comment: @animuson Right.  I should have added it in my question.  But I thought Moderators decision is final.  Moderator wants to give some importance but it is not accepted by community. Why it happened?  or my understanding about "notice added" is wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I added the post notice.

One of the (now deleted) comments posted to the question had *already* tried to give a partial answer his homework question, but without any explanation describing how the answer had been formulated.  This doesn't help anyone, least of all the OP.

Comment: I expected that you're going to answer my question.  But I thought Moderators decision is final. Moderator wants to give some importance but it is not accepted by community. Why it happened? or my understanding about "notice added" is wrong?

Comment: Wait, what? ....  All the notice says is don't expect your answer to still be here if you don't include some explanation with it.